# Number of implicants in case of don't cares

Tags: digital-logic

How many **implicants** are present in the given k-map?
[image]

I know that there are 6 prime implicant and 0 essential prime implicants.

My attempt:-
by taking each 1 and X individually(as a product term) we get 6 implicants-
[image: size-1 implicant]

by pairing we get 6 more implicants-
[image]

so finally we have **12 implicants**

Is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

(It has been a while since I took digital logic classes, but ...)
Considering that the Xs are don't-cares they do not **need** to be included in the minimized logic expression and are there to be used only if needed. Also, prime implicants are supposed to maximize the number of cells (1s and X) they include, that being in order to reduce the expression. I would not count the groups 1 and 6, because they only link Xs, and the single cells such as groups 2 and 4 of your first picture, are not prime implicants because they don't maximize the number of cells they group. So, counting possible implicants (though not prime implicants) I guess you cound count the two lone 1s in the first picture and the groups 2, 3, 4 and 5 of the second picture posted.

[image: K-map for the given problem]

Comment: Since 1 and 6 are prime implicants so shouldn't they be implicants?

Comment: https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/classes/su15/cse140-a/slides/lec4_ann.pdf page 30 has a definition for implicants, through it, "A product term that has non-empty intersection with on-set F and does not intersect with off-set R". So, for a grouping to be an implicant, it has to have at least a 1, it cannot include the empty cells (zeros) and has to obey the k-map possible groupings

Comment: Following that definition, the individual 1s are implicants, the individual Xs are not. The pairs of 1s and Xs are implicant if they obey the k-map possible groupings, but groups of Xs are not implicant if they don't include at least a 1.

Comment: your edit adds a different question, and, it seems to be counting just single 1s as "implicants" and not all possible terms that are implicants, as your first question seems to define. Maybe it should be another question

Comment: "A product term that has non-empty intersection with on-set F and does not intersect with off-set R". What does on-set and off-set means?

Comment: So should i have to ask second part of my question separately?

Comment: the on-set is the set of all the inputs that should make the output be 1 (on) and the off-set is the same but for being 0 (off), the don't-cares are not in any of the sets, so you can use them as needed to minimize the terms.

Comment: You probably should ask the second part separately, and do check if someone has already asked it. Seems like that author has a different definition of counting the implicants.