# Number of implicants in given k-map

Tags: digital-logic

Why pairs and quad of 1's are not counted as implicants in the given k-map
[image]
ref:- https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/digital-logic-implicants-k-map/amp/

Comment: See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/450714/152903

Comment: I would say this page is misinterpreting the term "implicant".

Comment: There must be a wealth of information on this topic available online. Have you tried looking at any other sources? Tried searching for "implicant"?

Comment: Ok.. I'll try to somewhere else to search for "implicant"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Prime Implicants and Essential Prime Implicants in K Map](http://www.electronicsandcommunications.com/2018/03/prime-implicants-and-essential-prime.html)

> S is an implicant of the function f if and only if the value S is equal to 1 so that the value of the function f is also equal to 1.
>
> a minterm will be an implicant, but an implicant need not be a minterm.

So [Digital Logic | Implicants in K-Map](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/digital-logic-implicants-k-map/) use of implicant is implying a minterm is an implicant, which disagrees with the above definition.

\$ ABC\$, \$ ABC \bar D\$ & \$ ABCD\$ are all implicants, but only 1 is a prime implicant.

[image]

So 8 minterms + 5 prime = 13 implicants, 5 prime, 4 essential & 1 redundant.