# Number of Prime Implicants VS Essential Prime implicants with don't care

Tags: boolean-algebra, karnaugh-map

So the Prime implicants are those largest square or rectangle made up of bunch of adjacent minterms
Essential Prime implicants are those prime implicants which also cover a particular midterm/s.
But I can't find much definition about when the function has don't care.
This [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/450714/number-of-implicants-in-case-of-dont-cares) asks about implicant, but not the essential ones

Let's say we have a function as f(x,y,z)=m(0,1,6,7)

the K-map as:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| c\ab |      |      |     |     |
--------------------------------------------------
|      |   1  |      |  1  |     |
--------------------------------------------------
|      |   1  |      |  1  |     |
--------------------------------------------------
```

From the k-map, we can see there are 4 implicants and 2 prime implicants and 2 essential prime implicants, right ?

My questions is: Are don't-cares considered as 1/0 when we counting essential/prime /implicants as well once we mark them as 1/0?

Now we have a similar function as f(x,y,z)=m(0,1,6,7) + d(2,3)
so the k map as:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| c\ab |      |      |     |     |
--------------------------------------------------
|      |   1  | x(1) |  1  |     |
--------------------------------------------------
|      |   1  | x(1) |  1  |     |
--------------------------------------------------
```

In this k-map, we have 6 implicants for each one: and 2 prime implicants from

```
1 x(1)
1 x(1)
```

of the left and

```
 x(1) 1
 x(1) 1
```

Of the right.

and 2 essential prime implicants from those prime implicants.

so 6 implicants and 2 prime implicants and 2 essential prime implicants for  f(x,y,z)=m(0,1,6,7) + d(2,3).

Comment: You have only one (single) prime implicant for both cases.

Comment: Are the only prime implicants the essential one for each case?

Comment: [This](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/various-implicants-in-k-map/) explains all about implicants of K-Map. do't-care is conveniently taken as  either '0' or '1'.